# Is using a Google Drive client together with a sync tool a good or bad idea?

Tags: sync, google-drive, unison

I have an employer-provided Google Drive account with almost 1 TB of data on. Basically everything I work on is on the Google Drive. It functions as a sort of live backup. Also, I'm running Ubuntu.

Now, back in the days on Windows, there was a Google Drive client that synced selected folders to my hard drive, which worked great, because I didn't have to wait for the client to download every single file when opening them.

Currently on Ubuntu, I'm using google-drive-ocamlfuse which is real steady, but extremely slow.

So I was thinking about using a syncing tool, e.g. unison, to sync files from my google-drive-ocamlfuse folder to a regular folder, so I can access files on the fly, but still have them uploaded to my Google Drive "live".

Is this a great idea, or a prescription for disaster?

Comment: Did you tried Grive? I have set up it with [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012861/66509).

Comment: I tried using one-drive to sync my google-drive which worked (in a fashion) but the biggest difficulty I found was that there is no app which will open google-sheets natively. So in the end, I decided that as I have now managed to mount google-drive automatically on start up, acsess is persistently good so there is no need (for me anyway) to sync my google-drive locally.